# WFC SVC File emits HTML when called from a service client

Tags: wcf, iis-6

I'm in the process of deploying a WCF service application.  The service works fine if it's running as its own site, but the intention is for the service to run as a virtual directory of the Default web site of the server.  When I set the service up in this configuration, I get an odd problem.  When the client tries to make a service call, it receives the HTML of the friendly service description, not SOAP.  Naturally this generates a service error.  The HTML appears to be identical to the service page that you see in a browser with an HTTP Get, but I'm only seeing the first 1024 bytes in the error message, so I may be missing something.

I've checked HttpHandlers and loaded assemblies, and as far as I can tell there's nothing unusual that is being inherited by the virtual directory.  The default site has 3 ISAPI Filters installed including Outlook Web Access (yes, this server is running Exchange).  I tried installing these filters in my test web site, but it still ran the service without problems.  The problem only happens with the service is running as a virtual directory of another virtual directory within the default web site.

The server is Windows Small Bus Server 2003 SP 2 running IIS6.

Answer (score 0):

If you're hosting WCF in IIS you need to set the server up in the 'Application Role' check out the following link does that help:
[MSDN: Internet Information Service Hosting Instructions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751518.aspx)